# Ghostscript embedded fonts and substitution

Tags: pdf, fonts, jpeg, ghostscript

I'm converting PDF to JPG with gs.

Does gs substitute embedded fonts? How exactly this works? Like if i embed all fonts that is used in PDF does gs still look for some substitution or can it use that embedded font data?

So does embedding fonts in PDF mean that all glyphs used in PDF with that font is being embedded and i don't need to have that font in my gs font path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you’re outputting a JPEG file, you’re in effect outputting an image. This means that Ghostscript renders the page as image, then compresses the image using JPEG (lossy – to prevent reduced legibility of the text, use a lossless compression format such as PNG instead; JPEG is basically only good for photography because lossless would be much too big there).

In a bitmap image, there are no fonts, only pixels – so, for text rendering (e.g. black text on a white page), Ghostscript will create a bitmap image consisting only of greyscale pixels (by means of anti-aliasing), then save that.

To be able to do that, Ghostscript must have access to the fonts at the time of PDF rendering and JPEG creation. This means that the fonts either must be installed on the system (and in your font path), or embedded in the PDF in the first place. They are *not* necessary to view the JPEG file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer. I know jpg doesn't require font files :) Question is/was just that: is it enough to embed fonts or do i need to put them ALSO to server for converting. So does embedding include ALL necessary data to render font.

Comment: One of them, either have them on the server, or embed them into the PDF, is enough. (It is also acceptable to embed some, and have the others on the server.) Embedding a font into PDF contains (at the decision of the PDF creator) either the entire font, or a subset with *all* characters required to render that document, so embedding the font is, in both options, enough. You’re welcome ;)

Comment: Ok, why then when i'm debugging some PDF conversion there is lines in output like "Substituting font xxx to xx" EVEN when all needed fonts are embedded to pdf?

Comment: Can’t say without seeing it. Maybe someone didn’t embed all needed fonts. Acrobat Reader has a “List All Fonts...” button, for example.